# React js app is showing blank when hosted on netlify, render, and gh pages, but it is working on local server

Tags: reactjs, deployment, netlify

I've been struggling with this problem for the past 2 weeks. I've tried so many fixes but did not find any luck. It works on my local server but it does not work on netlify or render. Here is my github repo https://github.com/bilguun1130/new-bnb-lab. [How it looks on when hosted on render](https://i.stack.imgur.com/toAeN.png). [How it looks on my local machine](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eZBrp.png).

I've tried changing package.json. For example, I added
"predeploy":"npm run build",
"deploy":"gh-pages -d build"
to scripts and added "homepage": "https://bilguun1130.github.io" to the json and tried changing it to "https://bilguun1130.github.io/new-bnb-lab".

Comment: Your `gh-pages` works fine, you just didn't setup it to work from `gh-pages` branch in the settings

Comment: on github pages it is showing the getting started with create react app page instead of my app. Idk why.

Comment: [YOU HAVE TO CHANGE THE SOURCE BRANCH IN THE PAGES SETTINGS](https://docs.github.com/en/pages/getting-started-with-github-pages/configuring-a-publishing-source-for-your-github-pages-site#publishing-from-a-branch)

Comment: It kinda works which I'm very happy of. However, some sections and icons are not visible for some reason. For example, Testimonials section is invisible or gone while it is visible on local machine. Also, title reads react app not bnb lab for some reason.